# How can I prevent the child view being cut off when I add a tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontainerview, tabbarcontroller

I want the **green view** to move forward from the **container view** as follows.
[image: image1]

However, when I add a **tab bar controller**, the **green view** is cut off as follows.
[image: image2]

I tried the following codes so that the **green view** is not cut off. But it did not work.

```
containerView.clipsToBounds = false
containerView.layer.zPosition = 100
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: containerView)
```

The problem seems to be not in the *container view*. Because when *tab bar controller* was added, *green view* started to be cut off.
When I add a **tab bar controller**, how can I prevent the **green view** from being cut off?

Comment: add it to main controller above the container view

Comment: What you can do is subview the greenview in the tabbarcontroller instead of subviewing it in the your tabbar child controller. But I'm not sure if its a good practice.

Comment: just add it to main or set clips to bound false for parent view of this view

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that UITransitionView in your UITabBarController clips all subviews. You can fix this easily if you remove clipsSubview from every subview in your TabBarController. I make this with custom TabBarController. Here is my code

```
class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for item in self.view.subviews{
            item.clipsToBounds = false
        }
        self.view.clipsToBounds = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, its working! I've tried "self.view.clipsToBounds = false" code before in my CustomTabBarViewController. But I have not tried to add it for all the items.

Comment: I don't access to outter green view when i added to gesture to green view. How can i solve this?